# What does the Json onLoad do and how can i return something via the call?

Tags: javascript, json

```
function JsonCall() {
    JsonClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JsonClient.send(Data);     
    JsonClient.onload = function() {    
      SomeOtherFunction(this.responseText);      
    }           
}

// This function is in someother class.

    var Object = {
        SomeOtherFunction: function() {
         return data;
        }
   }
```

1. What will my JsonCall function
   return?
2. Can i do something where i can
   return the value from onLoad call of
   Json Object?

**I want to do some logic in my other class and return the value via this JsonCall function**

Comment: @Felix Kling: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.2/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks odd to me. The `JsonClient` object is supposed to be a `XHR` object here. However, a `XHR` object offers a `onreadystatechange` event to handle a complete transfer by checking the `readyState` attribute.

The only exception is a `XDomainRequest` object from the Internet Explorer. That object indeed has an `.onload` property. Right now, your `JsonCall()` methods returns `undefined`. You would need to add a `callback method` to execute. Like

```
function JsonCall( SomeOtherFunction ) {
    JsonClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JsonClient.send(Data);     
    JsonClient.onload = function() {    
      SomeOtherFunction(this.responseText);      
    }           
}
```

and then call it like

```
JsonCall( Object.SomeOtherFunction );
```

where I hope `Object` is just an example word here.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the Json onLoad do

You assign a function to it. It runs the function when the HTTP response has arrived.

> and how can i return something via the call?

You can't. This is event driven programming. When an event happens, you can do something in response. You can't pause execution of code until the event happens and then carry on.

Whatever you need to do with the data, you have to do it in the callback function you assign to onLoad. You can't pass it back.